# Why is my search button so tiny and not appearing?

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpages/main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="KPIGen.admin.Data_Parameter_List" Codebehind="Data_Paramater_List.aspx.cs" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Masterpages/main.Master" %>
<%@ OutputCache NoStore="true" Location="None" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="m" Runat="Server">
    <telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="ajaxmgr" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="kgDataParamList">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="kgDataParamList" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnSearch">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="kgDataParamList" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>    

    <asp:Button id="btnBackToMain" runat="server" Text="Go Back To Admin Main" OnClick="btnBackToMain_Click" CssClass="button" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" />


    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnSearch">
    <div class="formContainer">
        <div style="width:33%;float:left;">
            <IKS:DDL ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server"></IKS:DDL>
        </div>
        <div style="width:33%;float:left;">
            <IKS:DDL ID="ddlCategory" runat="server"></IKS:DDL>
        </div>
        <div style="width:33%;float:left;">
            <IKS:TXT ID="txtTitle" runat="server" MaxLength="200"></IKS:TXT> 
        </div>

        <div style="width:33%;float:left;">     
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <asp:Button id="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" CssClass="button" />
        </div>  
    </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:98%;">
       <IKS:KeyGrid ID="kgDataParamList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="kgDataParamList_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="kgDataParamList_ItemCommand" AllowPaging="false">
            <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" >      
                <CommandItemTemplate>
                    <a href="javascript:OpenDetail(0)" >
                        <asp:Image ID="imgAddTemplate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/16/form_blue_add.png" />
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltAddTemplate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </a>

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnSaveSortOrder" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnSaveSortOrder_Click" style="margin-left:10px;">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgSaveSortOrder" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/16/disk_blue.png" />
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltSaveSortOrder" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </CommandItemTemplate>  
                <CommandItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Height="24px" />
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="sortOrder" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdndpid" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="category" DataField="Category.Description" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="department" DataField="Department.Description" HeaderStyle-Width="15%"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="title" DataField="Title" HeaderStyle-Width="50%"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>                
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="actions" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlEdit" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClientClick="return lnkDelete_Click()"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </IKS:KeyGrid>       
    </div>

    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="scriptBlock" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function OpenDetail(id) {

                OpenPopup("Data_Param_Details.aspx?id=" + id);
            }

            function lnkDelete_Click() {
                return confirm('<%= Config.Label.Get("LABEL_DELETE_CONFIRM") %>');
            }
        </script>     
    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>     
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="o" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified the "Text" property...